# Separate 3rd party modules

Tags: codeigniter

I going to start new Codeigniter application and trying to find a way to separate 3rd party modules source (for example Tank Auth) from my own code, 
What i need is to setup a file tree like the following:

- /project_root/

  - /system *(framework system - done)*
  - /3rd_party/

    - /dists/
    - /application/ *(installed 3d party libraries/modules - **the question topic**)*
  - /application/ *( my application - done)*
  - /site/ *(site root, working tree - done)*

The /system `/application` `/site` done using `index.php` and `application/config/config.php` settings.

Is there any correct way to acheive the tree like above  using configuration settings ?  I new for Codeigniter and have no idea if such is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a modular structure with Codeigniter, **Modular Extensions - HMVC** is the go-to solution:

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

For your setup, you would add this to your `config.php`:

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    // absolute path                    relative path
    APPPATH.'3rd_party/application/' => '../../3rd_party/application/',
);
```

- /project_root/

  - /system
  - /3rd_party/

    - /dists/
    - /application/

      - **tank_auth**
      - **my_module**
      - **some_other_third_party_code**
  - /application/
  - /site/

The "relative path" is relative to any sub directory in your application root, like `models`, `controllers`, `helpers`, etc. For example in CI you can load a "model" from a "view" directory if you use:

```
$this->load->model('../views/some_model');
```

...not that's it's something you would normally do - but this is how HMVC's loader works. HVMC can be used to load anything CI normally can but from a "module" directory. You can have as many different modules or module paths as you want.

Modules can (but don't have to) load controller and act like their own mini-application. You can also load dependencies cross-module, or from the default application root. 
You can still use your default application directory alongside modules. To specify that you want to load a particular asset from a module path, just include the module name in the path:

```
// Loads the "tank_auth" library (works from the tank_auth module)
$this->load->library('tank_auth');

// Loads the "tank_auth" library (works from anywhere in your application)
$this->load->library('tank_auth/tank_auth');
```

This works with models, helpers, etc. as well.

To access a controller in `tank_auth/controllers/login` you would use the URL `http://example.com/tank_auth/login`. You can also run a controller within another controller by using the `modules::run()` method, which could allow you to "wrap" controller methods of modules in your own logic without touching them:

```
class my_login extends MX_Controller {
    function index() {
        modules::run('tank_auth/login');
    }
}
```

It's pretty well documented and has been around for years. I have used HMVC in nearly every Codeigniter project I've ever done, I highly recommend it.

Comment: I saw from the comments (after I posted this) you had discovered HMVC on your own, but had a problem with views in sub directories or something? It should work fine - what was the issue?

Comment: btw what mean parameters in this array ? for me it works as the following:
`$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    ROOTDIR.'modules/' => '../../modules/',
    ROOTDIR.'third_modules/' => '../../third_modules/',
);`
and not want to work any other way (ROOTDIR is path to main directory which outside of document root (Site)

Comment: It works fine, just little issues, I switched to ion auth as more supported module, and found (same as in tank auth) that HMVC can't find views if they placed under `third_modules/auth/views/auth/` and I have to move all views from that dir to `third_modules/auth/views/` may be if I will  more familiar with HMVC and codeigniter i will ask them to apply a patch to fix that

Comment: Ah, I think the path may be confusing since `$this->load->view('auth/login')` could be `auth/views/auth/login` or `auth/views/login`... try changing your module name to something else like "tank_auth" and see if it works. You can use routing to change "tank_auth" to just "auth" in the URL. I will add this: Tank Auth isn't exactly meant to be a plug-and-play solution - it kind of expects you to customize it to work with your application - which is why it's so bare-bones.

Comment: I found that it easer to keep things as is, because all i need is to track which code is out of main project, what about $config['modules_locations']  ? i really not sure what means index and value here

Comment: `$config['modules_locations']`: The keys are absolute paths, the values are relative paths - *relative* to where the loader would normally look (for example in CI you *can* load a "model" from a "view" directory if you use `$this->load->model('../views/some_model');`... not that's it's something you would normally do). So if you had one module path in a dir called "mymodules", let's say it was at the root of your whole directory structure next to index.php: `array(FCPATH.'mymodules/' => '../../mymodules/')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [loader class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html) , that loads the library with `$this->load->library("path/to/module")` is using hard-coded "library" as folder name ([check the source of Loader.php](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/codeigniter/libraries/Loader.php.source.html)) . So, in other words all your modules and libraries have to reside in library folder

> - /project_root/
>
>   - /system (framework system - done)
>   - /library/
>
>     - /3rd_party/
>
>       - /application/

and load them then with `$this->load->library('3rd_party/application/tankh_auth.php`)`

The only way to correct this (and not using library folder)  is by overriding Loader class by [writing your own](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html).  create Loader.php in your `application` folder , in specific - `application/core` by overriding library method

```
class My_Loader extends CI_Loader {


  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

}

public function library($library = '', $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL){

  //override this method with your custom loader code 

   //eg  


  include_once($filepath."/".$library); //where your $filepath is path to your library,  

  $this->_ci_loaded_files[] = $filepath;  
  return $this->_ci_init_class($class, '', $params, $object_name);

  //again look at original methods and/or  write your own by referencing those
}



}
```

Comment: thank you, just now I trying to follow this way. will reply you back if it works

Comment: isn't it more correct to override `_ci_load_class` ? so i can switch over multiple `APPPATHs` to find correct class for autoloading ?

Comment: @eicto yeah you can do that. Initially i wrote to override _ci_load_class (however i was not sure if it used by library only, after on looking at it - yes, override that class) This will be also used by auto loader. Either way, you'll have to override the whole method with all the path checks and inputs, etc - just so have that layer of security/error handling. basically, copy/pasta the code and replace `libraries` reference  with either config value or constant would be my suggestion

Comment: Semms that not work, as 3rd party contain also controllers, which paths seems hardcoded in `core/CodeIgniter.php` and also used in `core/Router.php` . Seems the biggest problem that I can't override `core/CodeIgniter.php` as it is not class...

Comment: without this it seems it possible to use `$autoload['packages']`, I hoped to get additional goal to get a way to have standalone modules/ dir

Comment: @eicto you dont have to use auto loader . Extend the controller classs `My_contoller extends CI_controler` and in __construct you add list  of libraries you want to load (which in turn will use your extended Loader class e.g. `parent:construct(); $this->load->library()`  Note thou: your controllers have to extend My_controller

Comment: but it mean I will have to modify any 3rd party packages I want to use, what I think about now it is to make module/ controller which will load module/3rdparty_module/ controller, and I will be able to set paths do that 3rdparty_modules in the config

Comment: I found [this](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) seems after some fixing i can  get my goals with that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry yourself with HMVC (Although it is great), and you don't need `MY_Loader` either.

I would read through http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html - Namely the section on **Application "Packages"**

In here, you will see a method called

```
$this->load->add_package_path()
```

In which you can specify additional paths for the loader to look for you libraries.

Comment: yes.  but 'package' therm in codeigniter do not include controller paths so i went via HMVC, ony problem with that way that HMVC do not see view's subdirs inside module tree